# Dagger 2: Inject 2 different scopes into one object

Tags: android, dagger-2

Before someone starts marking this question as duplicated, let me say that I already checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037821/dagger-v2-inject-2-different-scopes-into-one-object), but it didn't solve my issue.

As the title says, I need to inject two objects from different scopes in other object.
Let's say we have the next situation:

We have a screen where we let a user sign up and then, in the same screen, we do some operation base on a user session (ex: do some sync).

For my project I was planning to use subcomponents. I have the next code (simplified) so far based on this [post](https://proandroiddev.com/dagger-2-part-ii-custom-scopes-component-dependencies-subcomponents-697c1fa1cfc):

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

  static AppComponent init(MyApplication application) {
    return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
        .appModule(new AppModule(application))
        .build();
  }

  UserSessionComponent plusUserSessionComponent(UserSessionModule userSessionModule);

  void inject(MyApplication application);
}

@Module
public class AppModule {

  private MyApplication myApplication;

  public AppModule(@NonNull MyApplication myApplication) {
    this.myApplication = myApplication;
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  public AppSignUp provideAppSignUp() {
    return new AppSignUp();
  }
}

@UserSessionScope
@Subcomponent(modules = {UserSessionModule.class})
public interface UserSessionComponent {

  static UserSessionComponent init(AppComponent appComponent,
      UserSession userSession) {
    return appComponent.plusUserSessionComponent(userSession);
  }

  void inject(MyApplication myApplication);
}

@Module
public class UserSessionModule {

  private UserSession userSession;

  public UserSessionModule(@NonNull UserSession userSession) {
    this.userSession = userSession;
  }

  @Provides
  @UserSessionScope
  public UserSessionSyncHelper provideUserSession(UserSession userSession) {
    return new UserSessionSyncHelper(userSession);
  }


  @Provides
  @UserSessionScope
  public UserSessionSync provideUserSession(UserSessionSyncHelper userSessionSyncHelper) {
    return new UserSessionSync(userSessionSyncHelper);
  }
}
```

Now, in order to make it simple now, let's say I have a component (an activity, viewmodel, presenter or whatever) which will have this two dependencies:

```
public MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Inject
  AppSignUp appSignUp;

  @Inject
  UserSessionSync userSessionSync;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //to inject appSignUp
    MyApplication.getAppComponent().inject(this);
  }

  public onUserCreated(UserSession userSession) {
    //to inject userSessionSync
    MyApplication.getUserSessionComponent().inject(this);
  }
}
```

My problem here is that Dagger will complain in the first inject because AppModile does not have userSessionSync. So the question is, how can I solve this issue? Does Dagger have any feature for this scenario?

I could only think in the next solution so far:

Make UserSessionSync independent from Dagger framework and inside

```
public class UserSessionSync {
  @Inject
  UserSessionSyncHelper userSessionSyncHelper;

  public UserSessionSync(){
    MyApplication.getUserSessionComponent().inject(this)
  }
}
```

In my opinion, this is not a good way to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Tried using Dagger-Android, works fine. Also module is not really needed for AppSignUp. @Inject constructor() with @Singleton will do it. Under the hood, it uses subcomponents.

```
@Module
abstract class AppModule {

    @Module
    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        @Provides
        @Singleton
        fun providesAppSignUp() = AppSignUp()

    }
}

@Singleton
@Component( modules = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, ActivityBindingModule::class, AppModule::class] )
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<MainApplication>

@Module
interface ActivityBindingModule {

    @UserScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector( modules = [MainActivityModule::class] )
    fun mainActivity() : MainActivity
}

@Module
abstract class MainActivityModule {

    @Module
    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        @Provides
        @UserScope
        fun providesUserSession() = UserSession()
    }
}

class UserSession

class AppSignUp

@Scope
annotation class UserScope

class MainApplication : DaggerApplication() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var appSignUp : AppSignUp

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().build()
    }

}

class MainActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var appSignUp: AppSignUp

    @Inject
    lateinit var appSignUp1: AppSignUp

    @Inject
    lateinit var userSession: UserSession

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your code shows how to inject objects in the activity and that is not my problem. Actually, I am using that but I didn't add it to this example. In your code, though the userSession is defined with userScope, it is being injected since the very beginning in the activity and it works as a singleton, on the other hand, in my example, the userSession has a custom scope and it should be injected when the app has a new user session (with the code I wrote that part is solved, though I do not know how a class can be injected with different objects having different scopes).

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/frogermcs/GithubClient. GithubClientApplication has the user management and has the explicit logic to reset upon user log out (kind of).

Comment: @LeandroOcampo In that case, UserComponent is a subcomponent of AppComponent and has visibility into the parent bindings. Invoking inject on UserComponent takes care of injecting bindings provided by AppComponent.